# Supported primitive descriptors list is empty for node when using sample pre-trained face-detection model openvino

Tags: python, openvino

I have run OpenVino many times on intel core series, RPI 4, NCS-1 and NCS-2. But I have the following issue when working with a Xeon CPU

System:
Intel Xeon CPU E5-2620 v4, 16GB RAM, Windows Server 2016

OpenVino Version:
2020.4

Model Name:
face-detection-0105 : tried all variants - FP16, FP32, INT8

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "face_detection.py", line 233, in
sys.exit(main() or 0)
File "face_detection.py", line 79, in main
exec_net = ie.load_network(network=net, num_requests=2, device_name=args.device)
File "ie_api.pyx", line 314, in openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.IECore.load_network
File "ie_api.pyx", line 323, in openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.IECore.load_network
RuntimeError: Supported primitive descriptors list is empty for node: 381/variance/Fused_Add_
```

Can someone please help me in resolving this?

Answer (score 1):

The error might be due to old OpenVINO version. Try updating to the latest OpenVINO release (2022.1) or the latest LTS release (2021.4.2).

Link to the download page:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/openvino-toolkit/download.html